# DRY Javascript for a real newbie

Tags: javascript, adobe, dry

I'm really new at Javascript (and coding in general) and I'm using it in a PDF form I'm creating.

This is what I want to do, but I know there's a better, DRYer way.

Appreciate your help.

```
this.getField("new_shares_A").display = display.hidden;
this.getField("new_shares_$_A").display = display.hidden;
this.getField("new_deb_A").display = display.hidden;
this.getField("new_deb_$_A").display = display.hidden;
this.getField("std_total_new_A").display = display.hidden;

if(getField("Elect").valueAsString==="A")
{
  this.getField("new_shares_A").display = display.visible;
  this.getField("new_shares_$_A").display = display.visible;
  this.getField("new_deb_A").display = display.visible;
  this.getField("new_deb_$_A").display = display.visible;
  this.getField("std_total_new_A").display = display.visible;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Seriously? A guy comes here looking for help and you tell him to go somewhere else? I thought stack overflow was supposed to be a friendly environment.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use an array of every field you're trying to get, and to figure out whether you want `.visible` or `.hidden` in advance:

```
const displayToUse = getField("Elect").valueAsString==="A"
? display.visible
: display.hidden;

[
  'new_shares_A',
  'new_shares_$_A',
  'new_deb_A',
  'new_deb_$_A',
  'std_total_new_A'
].forEach((field) => {
  this.getField(field).display = displayToUse;
});
```